# How to import cplex.jl on google colab

Tags: optimization, julia, google-colaboratory, cplex

I need to create a optimization problem with the cplex library and julia. I have to use colab for this, I was able to create a colab on the julia template and download the JuMP library. I have a student license on cplex. But when I try to download cplex it gives the following error:

```
Error building `CPLEX`: 
ERROR: LoadError: Unable to install CPLEX.jl.

The versions of CPLEX supported by CPLEX.jl are:

* 12.10
* 20.1

You must download and install one of these versions separately.

You should set the `CPLEX_STUDIO_BINARIES` environment variable to point to
the install location then try again. For example (updating the path to the
correct location if needed):


# On Windows, this might be
ENV["CPLEX_STUDIO_BINARIES"] = "C:\\Program Files\\CPLEX_Studio1210\\cplex\\bin\\x86-64_win\\"
import Pkg
Pkg.add("CPLEX")
Pkg.build("CPLEX")
```

i tried the `import Pkg; Pkg.add("CPLEX")`  and upload the I uploaded the cplex files on the computer and showed the path there:

```
ENV["CPLEX_STUDIO_BINARIES"] = "/content/x64_win64"
import Pkg
Pkg.add("CPLEX")
Pkg.build("CPLEX")
```